# Swift: How to convert a String to UInt8 array?

Tags: swift

How do you convert a String to UInt8 array?

```
var str = "test"
var ar : [UInt8]
ar = str
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Lots of different ways, depending on how you want to handle non-ASCII characters.

But the simplest code would be to use the `utf8` view:

```
let string = "hello"

let array: [UInt8] = Array(string.utf8)
```

Note, this will result in multi-byte characters being represented as multiple entries in the array, i.e.:

```
let string = "é"
print(Array(string.utf8))
```

prints out `[195, 169]`

There’s also `.nulTerminatedUTF8`, which does the same thing, but then adds a nul-character to the end if your plan is to pass this somewhere as a C string (though if you’re doing that, you can probably also use `.withCString` or just use the implicit conversion for bridged C functions.

Answer (score 13):

```
let str = "test"
let byteArray = [UInt8](str.utf8)
```

Answer (score 4):

swift 4

```
 func stringToUInt8Array(){

     let str:String = "Swift 4"
     let strToUInt8:[UInt8] = [UInt8](str.utf8)

     print(strToUInt8)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question looking for how to convert to a `Int8` array. This is how I'm doing it, but surely there's a less loopy way:

### Method on an Extension for `String`

```
public func int8Array() -> [Int8] {
    var retVal : [Int8] = []
    for thing in self.utf16 {
        retVal.append(Int8(thing))
    }
    return retVal
}
```

Note: storing a UTF-16 encoded character (2 bytes) in an Int8 (1 byte) will lead to information loss.

Comment: shouln't you use Int16 for utf16?

Comment: @marosoaie that would be good too. Depends what you're trying to get to. Surprisingly, INT8_MAX is only 127, which is a number that I've heard of and used before, so that's pretty scary. I'd probably just opt for `Int` if I had a choice and let iOS sort it out.

Comment: The problem is that int8 is 1 byte, and utf16 characters are 2 bytes. Storing one utf16 character in a int8 is going to lead losing information and data corruption.