# String Array to Int8 Array byte TypeCasting

Tags: swift, arrays

The code which i am using but it shows an error of cannot invoke initializer for type array with argument list of string.utf8view

Help me to convert a string to signed int byte array

```
 static func stringToByteArray(string : String)-> Array<Int8> 
  {
        let array: [Int8] = Array(string.utf8)
        //print("string array \(array)")
        return array

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255402/swift-how-to-convert-a-string-to-uint8-array

Comment: yes i am using that same code but it is for UInt8, i need it for Int8 byte array conversion

Comment: why do you want to convert string to signed Int8 array ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this method that firstly convert your array to unsigned integer then to signed array as there is no method to typecast unsigned array to signed array directly.

```
 func stringToByteArray(string : String)-> Array<Int8>
    {
        let array: [UInt8] = Array(string.utf8)
        var arraySigned = [Int8]()
        var convertSigned: Int8!
        for element in array
        {
            convertSigned = Int8(bitPattern: element)
            arraySigned.append(convertSigned)
        }

        print("string array \(arraySigned)")
        return arraySigned

    }
```

Comment: @NishaNair: Don't forget to *accept* helpful answers!

Comment: Simpler: `let arraySigned = string.utf8.map { Int8(bitPattern: $0) }`